# Default value for bash read if input is null

Tags: bash

```
VOL="~/somepath/script.py"
    printf "Drag and drop the '/somepath/vol.py' file on terminal./nPress enter for [/home/$USER/somepath/script.py]"
    read directory=${directory:-$VOL}
```

Given the code above, how can I allow the script user press the ENTER key for a preconfigured path present on the script? In this case it should be /home/somepath/script.py

The one above doesn't work. It gives me a `read: 'directory=~/somepath/script.py': not a valid identifier` error.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Make it a separate step.

```
VOL="~/somepath/script.py"
printf "Drag and drop the '/somepath/vol.py' file on terminal.
  Press enter for [/home/%s/somepath/script.py]" "$USER"
read directory
: ${directory:=$VOL} # = rather than -
```

(Factor the `$USER` variable out to an argument rather than embedding it in the `printf`'s format specifier...)

`:` (synonym for `true`) is basically a no-op that won't throw an error, but the parser still evaluates its arguments. `:=` instead of `:-` does an *assignment* if there's no value, so it sets a default. :)

Or, you could use the defaulting assignment in any other statement, like logging output.

```
echo "Using '${directory:=$VOL}'"
```

This accomplishes the same thing.